# Set up persistent custom resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, chroot

I'm using a chromebook Pixel 2, with a 2560x1700 (3:2) display. My goal is to use a smaller 3:2 resolution.

For a while now, I've been using a few commands to reset the resolution on my Chroot of Unity 14.04 (commands below). This works fine as a temporary fix, but it's a little bothersome to reset the resolution to stock settings whenever I log in or out of the chroot.

Here are the commands I use:

```
cvt 1680 1120 60
xrandr --newmode "1680x1120_60.00" 157.00 1680 1792 1968 2256  1120 1123 1133 1162 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode eDP1 1680x1120_60.00
```

I attempted converting the commands to a bash file, but when run, xrandr gave many errors.

If I could simply add a 3:2 resolution (perhaps close to 1680x1120) to xrandr permanently, that would be perfect.

EDIT: I followed [this article on dnschneid's crouton wiki](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Chromebook-Pixel) to get my current results, which just need to be made persistent. It boils down to the three commands I posted before.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution -Adding undetected resolutions

Comment: Thanks for the reference. The link I just added in an update is from dnschneid's wiki, where he references those commands.

Comment: I just read through the "Setting xrandr changes persistently" section, and it looks like setting changes in xorg.conf is my best bet. However, the closest thing I can find is an xorg.conf.d directory with no internal files of similar names. I could not find a .xprofile file, and I'm not familiar with kdm or gdm.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the System Settings Display Settings to change the resolution. It should stay the same.
Although, to be honest, I don't understand why you would want to turn down the resolution. You have a very high resolution display, and so I think that instead of turning down the resolution (why waste all those pixels!), you should just adjust the scale of all text:

[image]

Comment: I'm glad you asked! I'd love to keep it the native resolution (which is a much smoother transition from ChromeOS too), but unfortunately Unity's menus and icons don't scale well. The launcher and panel do well enough, but the actual settings menus and file browser don't. If there's a scaling fix, that would be perfect.

Comment: @Pheonix Hmm... In my experience, stuff scales very well in Ubuntu (unlike in Windows). Maybe they added better support in 15.10, which is what I am using. Anyway, did you try using the "Resolution" setting? It should stay the same...

Comment: As far as using the slider you mentioned before, things like the "search" icon, mount/unmount icons and other similiar buttons don't scale. The text and window control buttons do, though. My biggest issue with that scaling method is non-resizable windows, in which words get cut off and crouded together. 
As far as changing the resolution, I've been using 1680x1050 which does stay, but there's ugly letterboxes at the top and bottom that I'd like to get rid of..